# Swift extensions for `NSTextField` and `NSTextFieldCell`

Tags: swift, macos

I have an extension for NSTextField that will flash the background color. I now have the need to do the same thing for an NSTextFieldCell. I am trying to find a way to abstract the current extension to handle both. Currently the Copy->Paste solution is being used to meet a deadline but it duplicates 250 lines of code so I would like to refactor it to a proper solution.

The only class that I see they share is NSObject but since NSObject doesn't have backgroundColor most of the code fails and I can't find a way to constrain the extension with a 'where' clause to just the classes I need. It would be fine if it worked for any class with a backgroundColor but again I didn't see how with the where clause I could use check for a property or respondsToSelector.

I have also tried casting from NSTextField to NSTextFieldCell but that returns an error. (Cast to unrelated type always fails) I get the same error casting the other way as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have also tried casting from NSTextField to NSTextFieldCell

Because that's not how they are related. The relationship is that NSTextField has a `cell` which is an NSTextFieldCell. So if you've extended NSTextFieldCell you've effectively extended NSTextField already.